# function App.Support.Ticket.changeset/2 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I've just finished a course of Elixir and now I'm truing to run a project that was build on Phoenix 1.3, the project compiles well and local server starts without any errors but when I try to open a link I receive an error: 
[image: here is screenshot]

Here is a code of account.ex file:

```
defmodule App.Account do

  alias App.Repo
  alias Xarango.Query

  alias App.Account.User

  def list_users do
    User.list(%{})
  end

  def get_user!(id) do
    try do
      {:ok, User.one(%{_key: id})}
      rescue
      e in Xarango.Error ->
        {:error, :not_found}
    end
  end

  def get_user_by_attr(attr) do
    try do
      {:ok, User.one(attr)}
    rescue
      Xarango.Error ->
        key = attr
          |> Map.keys
          |> List.first
          |> Atom.to_string
        {:error, "#{key} not found"}
    end
  end

  def check_credentials(%{"password" => password, "email" => email}) do
    with {:ok, user} <- get_user_by_attr(%{email: email}) do
      if password = user.doc._data.password do
        {:ok, user}
      else
        {:error, "Incorrect password"}
      end
    end
  end

  def create_user(%{"email" => email, "nick" => nick} = attrs, roles) when is_list(roles) do
    with {:ok, _resp} <- check_if_attr_exists(%{email: email}),
         {:ok, _resp} <- check_if_attr_exists(%{nick: nick}),
         {:ok, user} <- get_avatar(attrs) do
      {:ok, user |> Map.put("roles", roles) |> User.create}
    end
  end

  defp get_avatar(%{"email" => email} = attrs) do
    hash_email = :crypto.hash(:md5, email) |> Base.encode16
    {:ok, Map.put(attrs, "avatar", "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/100/#{hash_email}")}
  end

  defp check_if_attr_exists(attr) do
    try do
      User.one(attr)
      key = attr
            |> Map.keys
            |> List.first
            |> Atom.to_string
      {:error, "#{key} already exists"}
    rescue
      Xarango.Error ->
        {:ok, :continue}
    end
  end

  def hash_password(%{"password" => password} = attrs) do
    with {:ok} <- valid_password?(password),
         %{password: _, password_hash: password} <- password do
      {:ok, Map.put(attrs, "password", password)}
    end
  end

  defp valid_password?(password) when byte_size(password) > 6 do
    {:ok}
  end

  defp valid_password?(_), do: {:error, "The password is to short"}

  def update_user(%User{} = user, attrs) do
    user
    |> User.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.update()
  end

  def delete_user(%User{} = user) do
    Repo.delete(user)
  end

  def change_user(%User{} = user) do
    User.changeset(user, %{})
  end

  alias App.Account.Client

    Query.query(q).result
  end

  def get_client!(id) do
    q = """
    FOR c IN clients
        FILTER c._key == #{id}
        RETURN c
    """
    List.first Query.query(q).result
  end

  def create_client(attrs \\ %{}) do
    %Client{}
    |> Client.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end


  def update_client(%Client{} = client, attrs) do
    client
    |> Client.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.update()
  end


  def delete_client(%Client{} = client) do
    Repo.delete(client)
  end


  def change_client(%Client{} = client) do
    Client.changeset(client, %{})
  end
end
```

And here is my client.ex file:

```
defmodule App.Account.Client do
  use Xarango.Domain.Document, collection: :clients

end
```

Here is part of my ticket_controller.ex file:

```
defmodule AppWeb.TicketController do
  use AppWeb, :controller

  alias App.Support
  alias App.Support.Ticket

  action_fallback AppWeb.FallbackController

  def index(conn, _params) do
    IO.inspect(Support.create_ticket())
    tickets = Support.list_tickets()
    render(conn, "index.json", tickets: tickets)
  end
```

**UPDATE** I put here also a code of my ticket.ex file (App.Support.Ticket):

```
defmodule App.Support.Ticket do
  use Xarango.Domain.Document, collection: :helpdesk_tickets


end
```

Any idea? Can somebody explain me what exactly I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 2:** I added a file repo.ex to folder /lib/app/repo.ex, which I took from working project:

```
defmodule App.Repo do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :app

  @doc """
  Dynamically loads the repository url from the
  DATABASE_URL environment variable.
  """
  def init(_, opts) do
    {:ok, Keyword.put(opts, :url, System.get_env("DATABASE_URL"))}
  end
end
```

Also I fixed a problem with ecto:

```
(CompileError) lib/app/repo.ex:2: module Ecto.Repo is not loaded and could not be found
   (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
   lib/app/repo.ex:2: App.Repo (module)
   (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:198: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

I fixed it by adding {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.2"} to deps in mix.exs and runnig ">mix deps.get".
For now I have a new error:

```
== Compilation error in file lib/app/repo.ex ==
** (ArgumentError) missing :adapter configuration in config :app, App.Repo
    lib/ecto/repo/supervisor.ex:70: Ecto.Repo.Supervisor.compile_config/2
    lib/app/repo.ex:2: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:198: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/6
```

Can somebody suggest what should I fix now? I feel like this error appears because I copied repo.ex file from the project that connects to PostgresDB and my current project connects to ArangoDB.

Comment: Please show us `App.Support.Ticket` module. Also, [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help to receive an answer.

Comment: @mudasobwa I've added code of App.Support.Ticket module, what about MCVE... I can try to build  a simple project which will generate same error, it will take some time